# switch statement ends up going through default, always

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Hello everyone as the title says as I run through my code everything works fine, it loops correctly but somehow ends up always picking up the default case before restarting the loop.

I'll post my code through pastebin since it's quite long:

https://pastebin.com/TxvH3MhJ

```
  while(myScore != "new" || myScore != "NEW" || myScore != "New"){

        switch(s2){
         case 1 :
          switch(s3){
          // code
           }


          default :
                cout<<("\nSomething went wrong, please restart the program.");   
                break; //this statement works correctly.

            }


        default : //this statement is always brought up each time i type "new", i also added a cout s2 to check if actually somehow the variable was changing mid code but it prints out correctly.
        cout<<("\nSomething went wrong please restart the program.");
        cout<<s2;
        break;`
```

p.s. I'm a beginner please bear in mind that probably the code is very rudimental although it is doing the job. at the moment the code just works if you enter 1s because i'm just working out the logic.

Comment: Undoubtedly the problem is that you are missing `break;` where it needs to be. And I can tell that without even looking at the code.

Comment: Before the `default:` a `case` should end in `break`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break;` breaks out of the innermost switch (or loop) only. So you need to place it after inner `switch`es too (unless you would need fall-through), like:

```
switch(s1) {
case 1:
    switch(s2) {
    ...
    }
    break; // <== HERE
case 2:
    ...
    break;
default:
    ....
    break; // optional
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much, i forgot a break due to my bad formatting.. thanks a lot!